Include \subsubparagraph hierarchical level
I need to include \subsubparagraph hierarchical level. So, I used this options for a subsubparagraph command:
\makeatletter\newcounter{subsubparagraph}[subparagraph]\renewcommand\thesubsubparagraph{%
  \thesubparagraph.\@arabic\c@subsubparagraph}\newcommand\subsubparagraph{%
  \@startsection{subsubparagraph}    % counter
    {6}                              % level
    {\parindent}                     % indent
    {3.25ex \@plus 1ex \@minus .2ex} % beforeskip
    {-1em}                           % afterskip
    {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}\newcommand\l@subsubparagraph{\@dottedtocline{6}{10em}{5em}}\newcommand{\subsubparagraphmark}[1]{}\makeatother

However, the complete objective was not achieved.
The difficulty is that I am not an expert in these latex commands, which prevents me from fully performing the task.
When I followed this instructions, in fact, the hierarchical level of \subsubparagraph appeared in the text, however, in the summary this hierarchical level did not appear. Also, between the \subsubparagraph and the text, there is no paragraph.
In addition, in the "file outline" column of the Overleaf LaTex Editor this hierarchical level also does not appear.
I made several modifications, but I was not successful. Can you help me overcome these difficulties?

Welcome to TeX.SX!

For the subsubparagraph to show up in the Table of Contents (I'm assuming you mean that with "summary") you need to adapth the counter tocdepth. For them to be numbered you need to set secnumdepth.
To have the text start below your subsubparagraph heading instead of in the same line make sure that the skip after the heading is positive (LaTeX uses the sign of that space to decide whether it should start in the same line -- negative -- or in a line below it).
Put together into an MWE:
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcounter{subsubparagraph}[subparagraph]
\renewcommand\thesubsubparagraph{%
  \thesubparagraph.\@arabic\c@subsubparagraph}
\newcommand\subsubparagraph{%
  \@startsection{subsubparagraph}    % counter
    {6}                              % level
    {\parindent}                     % indent
    {3.25ex \@plus 1ex \@minus .2ex} % beforeskip
    {1.5ex \@plus .5ex \@minus .2ex}  % afterskip
    {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\newcommand\l@subsubparagraph{\@dottedtocline{6}{10em}{5em}}
\newcommand{\subsubparagraphmark}[1]{}
\makeatother

\setcounter{tocdepth}{6}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{6}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\subsubparagraph{This is a subsubparagraph}
This is text in this paragraph. Isn't this great?
\end{document}


